# Copy cell formula with iteration

Tags: excel, excel-formula, iteration, cell

I am trying to solve a small problem. I have two rows with numbers and empty cells.

For example:

```
| 2005 | 2005 |      |      |
|      | 2007 |      | 2015 |
```

I need to create formula which will be located in the whole second row. If there is a number in first row then it counts number 2 to it and write result into the cell bellow. If cell in first row is empty and there is a number in the second row then the number remain unchanged. If there is no number in both cells, both will remain completely empty.

```
=IF(A6="";IF(ISNUMBER(A7);A7;"");A6+2)
```

I have this so far and it is almost working but when I copy formula by draging, it will erase numbers from second row if there is no number in the first row.

I do not know why it is not working. I allowed iterative calculation. I am using Microsoft Excel 2013.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Big thanks for editing the post. I am new to this forum and just starting to know things around here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have a formula **and** a value in the same cell.

If you add a formula, for instance, where `2007` is, it will surely erase `2007`. There is nothing you can do about it.

But you can create a new table below and do the following:

```
_____|   A  |  B   |  C   |  D   |
6    | 2005 | 2005 |      |      |
7    |      | 2007 |      | 2015 |
8    |      |      |      |      |
9    | =A6  | =B6  | =C6  | =D6  |
10   |form. |form. |form. |form. |
```

Use your **formula** where `form.` is written.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I am editing quite a big sheet and I was trying to make it as simple as it could be and I ended up at irresolvable task. Thanks for your help.